# Why does this stuck transaction not appear on etherscan?

Tags: nft, coinbase

Can anyone help? I have a stuck transaction in my Coinbase Wallet. Its status is marked as "Pending", and this has been the case for about 10 days now.

After doing some research, I've learned that if I create a transaction with the same nonce as the stuck transaction, but with a higher gas fee, the stuck transaction will effectively be cancelled, allowing subsequent transactions to then flow freely. (I have another 3 transactions that are also "Pending", which I believe are not going through due to the jammed transaction).

However, I cannot perform this operation, as there is a problem: When I press "View on block explorer" from within the Coinbase Wallet app, to see it on Etherscan, the Etherscan page that opens just says "Sorry, we are unable to locate this TxnHash". So I cant get the nonce.

I have contacted Coinbase asking them why their wallet app shows a stuck transaction but I can't see that transaction anywhere else, but they seem to be ignoring my messages.

I initialised the transaction from the Rarible web app, and its a transaction to burn an NFT that I minted. (Video format was corrupted).

Does anyone know if there is a legitimate reason for the transaction not showing up on Etherscan, other than the possibility that the Coinbase Wallet app has malfunctioned? And more importantly, how can I get this NFT burning transaction to go through? (Or if not,  perhaps delete it and create a new one?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue today, have you tried reloging into your coinbase wallet? It may be trivial but it worked for me. Just remember to have your pass code saved.

Comment: Legend, logging out worked. Transaction has gone through after being stuck for 2 weeks.